# Probability of Independent Events: Correct Expression

Tags: probability

A1,A2,..,A25 are independent events, each having probability p of occurring.

What is the expression for P(A1 U A2 U .... U A25)?

I'm thinking that the correct expression would be (1-p)^25 but am not too sure.

Comment: Hint: Use De Morgan's laws and the fact that
$$
X ~\text{and}~Y~\text{independent} \Rightarrow P(X~\text{and}~Y) = P(X) P(Y)
$$

Answer (score 1):

No. Probability of the complementary event is $(1-p)^{25}$ so the correct answer is $1-(1-p)^{25}$.